# Create Child Git Repository

Tags: git

I have a TFS GIT repository called Template. We want to create multiple child repositories from it, and then be able to push changes from parent to child.

Sequence would be:

**Part 1**

1. Complete setup of Template and label it v1.
2. Create child repository App1
3. Push Template into App1

**Part 2** - At some point in the future

1. Make changes to Template and label it v2.
2. Push label v2 into App1.

I looked around and couldn't quite find how to make part 2 happen. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you show what commands you used for Part1? That would help understand your setup and clarify what you need for Part2. Also, what is the relation of v2 with respect to v1? Is it just downstream on the same branch?

Comment: Do `git submodule` you need?

Comment: Don't do with submodules or separate repos what you can do with branching.

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is to use the templates as a submodule of App1.  That is, your parent/child relationship seems inverted.

Comment: We are setting up repository that will serve as template for other repositories

<code>
1. Create <Template> repository and initialize
2. Create <Replica> repository
3. Create bare mirrored clone and and push to mirror
 git clone --mirror <Template>
 cd <Template>.git
 git remote set-url --push origin <Replica_URL>
 
Now I made changes in <Template> and pushed to the repository. I ran the following commands in <Replica> expecting the results to come over but they didn't
 git fetch -p origin
 git push --mirror
</code>

Answer (score 1):

While I think it would be a relatively rare use case for which this is the best way to share code, let's look at what it would take.

If you want the `Template` repo to push changes to the `App1` repo, then within `Template` you need to configure `App1` as a remote.

```
/repos/template $  git remote add App1 url/of/app1/repo
```

Then `Template` is just like any local repository contributing to `App1`.  That means that each time you create a new app repo based on the template, you'll have to add it as another remote in the `Template` repo.  Also note that `git push` only interacts with one remote at a time, so you would probably want to put together a script for pushing updates to all of the app repos.

(As an aside, this feels backward - and I think you would be better off making `Template` a remote of each app repo, and setting each app repo up to monitor for, and `pull`, changes from `Template`.  This just seems like a more git-friendly way to do what you're trying to do - and that will be reflected in complexities as we continue describing how the `push` process would really work.  But if you want a push process, then having `Template` "contribute" to each app repo by treating the app repos as remotes is the way to do it.)

Now the thing is, a `push` *cannot* perform merges.  So you need for every app repo to have a branch that *only* advances when `Template` pushes to it, and then someone is still going to have to incorporate those changes into the branch(es) used for local changes to the app.  When you push from `Template` to app repo(s), you'll have to make sure you push the new changes to the app repos' template branches.

In truth, you're likely better off having such a branch regardless of whether you use a `push`- or `pull`-based mechanism.  The only difference is how the `Template`-driven branch gets updated.  But if you used a pull-based model, then each repo would be responsible for its single template branch's upstream relationship to the Template repo, rather than the Template repo (and/or the push commands issued to it) having to maintain *all* of the template branch relationships.

Anyhow, then in `App` you'd have something like

```
T0 <--(template)
  \
   A -- B <--(master)
```

After a while in the `Template` repo you make some changes, and you `push` those changes to `App`s `template` branch

```
T0 -- T1 <--(template)
  \
   A -- B <--(master)
```

and then someone will have to merge `template` into `master` and resolve any resulting conflicts.

```
T0 ------ T1 <--(template)
  \         \
   A -- B -- M <--(master)
```

And this can repeat as needed.  Of course, if you have multiple branches in the app repo, you'll need to figure out how to propagate the new template changes to each of them.  That could get quite tedious if there are many branches and conflicts that need resolved in each (though perhaps you could leverage `git rerere` to make it less troublesome).  This is why I think that, rather than a `push`- or `pull`-based scheme, finding a way to separate common code and use your build system to treat it as a dependency may serve you better, if it is practical for the type of common code you're dealing with.

Comment: So I am not a git expert, but here's what I did

Comment: So I am not a git expert but here's what I did

1. Create <Template> repository and initialize
2. Create <Replica> repository
3. Create bare mirrored clone and and push to mirror
 git clone --mirror <Template>
 cd <Template>.git
 git remote set-url --push origin <Replica_URL>
 
Now I made changes in <Template> and pushed to the repository. I ran the following commands in <Replica> expecting the results to come over but they didn'tfs
 git fetch -p origin
 git push --mirror